# xpages: convert from org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.library to extension library?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

Is there an easy way to modify an application that has been built using bootstrap4xpages so it now uses that same code that has become part of the extension Library?  This would allow the application to get the updates as I guess the bootstrap4xpages plugin won'T be updated anymore.

Thanks  :)

Comment: Remove the dependency from xsp.properties and re-build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the application uses the Select2 control, you'll still need both in the xsp.properties. That's because there are licensing issues that prevented the Select2 control being included in Extension Library plugin.

Otherwise, as Per says, you can just remove the org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.library reference from the xsp.properties.

Comment: Thanks Paul and Per.  Shold have thought about that... The app does use the Select2 so I guess I'll have to install the bootstrap4xpages plugin as well as the Extension Library.

Comment: Select2 could be added manually I'd think.  You'd get a more recent version that way I'm sure.